# Append a custom date to file name that increases by one second

Tags: linux, bash

So, I generated like thousands of images that I need to rename with this format:

**19-10-2022 17-35-10** (HH:MM:SS format)

And the next one should be:

**19-10-2022 17-35-11** (increases by one second) and so on.

Also, my images are perfectly numbered (like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and so on)

Is there any way to archieve this with a bash script or something? I would like to specify the starting date as well.

Edit: I have already searched for this question all over internet and I couldn't find any useful information. All I find is how to append regular dates and not a custom one that increases by one second like I am asking here.

Edit 2: I need it to be a different starting date than "now".

Comment: That's not going to work. You can't have forward slashes in filenames in Linux.

Comment: @tink Yeah, forward slashes can be changed to something else. I just need to rename all images at once as I explain.

Comment: You can find bunch of useful information with the keywords such as `add seconds to date bash`.

Comment: Should date in filename be related to its current name? You can use `date +"%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S" -d "@${DATE}"` to get date string for specific number of seconds since epoch in `DATE` variable.

Comment: @dimich Thanks! But the thing is that I need the starting date to be different than "now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert starting date to number of seconds since epoch, then add number from file name (or do any other arithmetics):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

START=$(date +"%s" -d "2022-10-20 13:00")

for F in *.png; do
    N="${F%.png}"
    DATE=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S" -d@$((${START}+${N})))
    mv -v "${F}" "${DATE}.png"
done
```

UPD: this will work with perfectly named files but will fail on non-numerical names. Also it  rename several files to the same name if you have something like `7.png`, `07.png`, `007.png`. If you want to handle any file names, just discard original name and increase `START` by 1 for each rename.

Comment: @tink Number to add is extracted from file name, so it should work correctly. Your note is true for second suggestion with incrementing START by 1. Yes, if order is important, some kind of numeric sorting is required.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was focusing on the first part, and this does indeed to what it is meant to.

Comment: I'm worrying about daylight saving. Different numbers of seconds could be represented as the same timestamp. Maybe `-u` is required for `date` to force UTC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the numeric sort order from the original files:

```
#!/bin/bash
stamp=1666175710     # "Seconds since epoc, manually entered"
readarray -d '' images < <(printf '%s\0' *.png | sort -zV)
for i in "${images[@]}"
do
  mv "$i" "$(date -d "@${stamp}" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").png"
  stamp=$(( stamp + 1 ))
done
```

I also chose a naming closely related to iso-8601 which will allow for the natural sorting of the renamed files.

Comment: Ooops ... typo. I had tested the local copy w/ the name start, changed it here but overlooked one occurrence. Thank you @XinCheng !